# Saved Machine Learning Model using Pickle won't predict text values properly

Tags: python, machine-learning, pickle, text-classification

I currently have a Machine Learning model which would predict what part of speech does a current word belong to

```
penn_results = penn_crf.predict_single(features)
```

and then, I made a code wherein it makes a print making a (word, POS) style print;

```
penn_tups = [(sent.split()[idx], penn_results[idx]) for idx in range(len(sent.split()))]
```

and when I try to run this, it gives me this output.

**[('The', 'DT'), ('quick', 'JJ'), ('brown', 'NN'), ('fox', 'NN'), ('jumps', 'NNS'), ('over', 'IN')] [('The', 'DET'), ('quick', 'NOUN'), ('brown', 'ADJ'), ('fox', 'NOUN'), ('jumps', 'NOUN'), ('over', 'ADP')]**

and so  I saved this model using

```
penn_filename = 'ptcp.sav'
pickle.dump(penn_crf, open(penn_filename, 'wb'))
```

Upon trying to run the model by loading hte saved pickle file with this

```
test = "The quick brown fox jumps over the head"
pickled_model = pickle.load(open('penn_treebank_crf_postagger.sav', 'rb'))
pickled_model.predict(test)
print(pickled_model.predict(test))
```

It prints this
**[['NNP'], ['NNP'], ['NNP'], ['NNP'], ['NNP'], ['NNP'], ['NNP'], ['NNP'], ['NNP'], ['NNP'], ['NNP'], ['NNP'], ['NNP'], ['NNP'], ['NNP'], ['NNP'], ['NNP'], ['NNP'], ['NNP'], ['NNP'], ['NNP'], ['NNP'], ['NNP'], ['NNP'], ['NNP'], ['NNP'], ['NNP'], ['NNP'], ['NNP'], ['NNP']]**

How can I make it print the accurate predicted values like this
**[('The', 'DT'), ('quick', 'JJ'), ('brown', 'NN'), ('fox', 'NN'), ('jumps', 'NNS'), ('over', 'IN')] [('The', 'DET'), ('quick', 'NOUN'), ('brown', 'ADJ'), ('fox', 'NOUN'), ('jumps', 'NOUN'), ('over', 'ADP')]**

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do **not** post screenshots - copy & paste the output of your code here as *text*.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you notice that your last `print` prints only the predicted POS tag? Naturally this doesn't include the word, you need to print it explicitly of you want it.

Comment: Hi, I tried to reformat my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Caution: this code was not tested.*

Replace the last line

```
print(pickled_model.predict(test))
```

with something like this:

```
tokens_test = test.split()
predictions_test = pickled_model.predict(test)
pairs_test = [(tokens_test[idx], predictions_test[idx]) for idx in range(len(tokens_test))]
print(pairs_test)
```

Comment: Thank you it worked, however, the predictions were wrong. It gave of **[('The', ['NNP']), ('quick', ['NNP']), ('brown', ['NNP']), ('fox', ['NNP']), ('jumps', ['NNP']), ('over', ['NNP'])]**. Any idea what causes this and how should this be fixed?

Comment: @nairedascie I don't know what kind type of model you're using, it's probably related to this. You use a function `predict_single` in the first example but you used a different one `predict` at the end, I don't know why? Maybe you should use `predict_single` then.

Comment: I tried doing predict_single, and it somehow partially did the right thing. I don't know why it doesn't emit the same result as with it running within the model code and the saved model, but I think I can debug this on my own. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the feature function

```
penn_results = penn_crf.predict_single(**features**)
penn_tups = [(sent.split()[idx], penn_results[idx]) for idx in range(len(sent.split()))]
```

In your current code

```
tokens_test = test.split()
**features function**
predictions_test = pickled_model.predict(test)
pairs_test = [(tokens_test[idx], predictions_test[idx]) for idx in range(len(tokens_test))]
print(pairs_test)
```

So that it would predict the same with your pre-saved model.

Comment: Yes, I think that's exactly what I'm lacking. I tried to add in my feature function and now my pickle file predicts the same way as my trained model. Thank you!